# css margin unexpected behaviour on block element

Tags: css, stylesheet

Suppose I have the following html code

```
<div class="f1">
  <div class="f2">
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following css applies to it

```
.f1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5em auto;
}


.f2 {
    background: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;  // this doesn't work
}
```

Then I saw a strange behaviour that margin-top property doesn't apply on class `.f2`. I don't why but when I add some padding or border on class `f1` then it work. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Ah yes, the collapsing margins thingy. Does [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is collapsing margins, check http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

You could add a `padding` to `.f1` instead of the `margin` from `.f2`.